It's more of a guess than an estimate. ("less of" vice "more of")

It's more of a guess than an estimate.

'more of' is an idiom according to my dictionary.
I wonder if I replace 'more' with 'less' to mean 'an esimate' is more accurate than 'a guess'.


It's less of a guess than an estimate.


If not possible, I wonder WHY because it's the same comparative construction/structure.
And what about the following? Are they idimomatic?


It's of a guess than an esimate.




It's of a guess rather than an estimate.



Thx. 'Less of A than B' = 'More of B than A] ?

What makes you suspect that your 2 and 3 might be idiomatic?

I was not sure because I am not native. But I tried regarding the 'of' in 'of a guess' as 'about' though there's 'than' which is a friend with 'comparative' and tried adding 'rahter' to 'than' such that 'rather' might not need 'comparative:more'.

Of doesn't mean 'about'. It belongs in the phrases less of and more of. (3) is OK if you leave out 'of'.

A > B more of A than B; A < B - more of B than A; A = B as much A as B.

If it is more of a guess than an estimate, as you suppose, you can say that it is less of an estimate than a guess. You must have 'more' or 'less'; your 2 and 3 are NOT idiomatic.

Informally, we already have a word to mean more of a guess than an estimate (within which the word of is syntactically and idiomatically optional). It's a guesstimate. But imho less of a guess than an estimate is a pointless thing to say anyway, and your suggestions #2 and #3 aren't even syntactically valid, let alone "idiomatic".

Any of these might answer the current question: be more (of) sth than sth OR "More an X" vs. "More of an X"? OR more of a ... vs more a.

@MichaelHarvey In your 'as much A as B', the 'much' is adjective or adverb?
